# GWT appstats + Gradle Error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gradle

I am working in a project that uses GWT and Google API engine. That project has no dependency manager then we are implementing Gradle.

The problem is that we are getting some errors during execution. Basically related with Appstats.

This is the error:

```
FAILED appstats: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.<init>(Recorder.java:209)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.<init>(Recorder.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.init(AppstatsFilter.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
   [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload{/,file:/home/crosa/work/moto_work/kaiju_gradle/war/},/home/crosa/work/moto_work/kaiju_gradle/war
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.<init>(Recorder.java:209)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder.<init>(Recorder.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.init(AppstatsFilter.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
   Resolving com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TimeItem
      Found type 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TimeItem'
         Resolving method setDisplayFormat
            Resolving annotation for java.lang.Deprecated
         Resolving method getDisplayFormat
            Resolving annotation for java.lang.Deprecated
   Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
```

Did someone of you guys had this error before?

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)`

That line means you're not using the AppEngine "launcher" (devserver). That's probably why Appstats don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are starting the application using:

```
mvn gwt:run
```

Instead of using:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```